# Play AVAudioPlayer after delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play two audio files (click and clack) back to back at an increasing frequency. It works as desired for the first second and then the sounds begin playing at the same time. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
static float clickClackDelay = 1.0;

- (void)runClickClackTimer {

    clickURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"click" withExtension:@"wav"];
    clackURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"clack" withExtension:@"wav"];
    avClick = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clickURL error:nil];
    avClack = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:clackURL error:nil];

    clickClack = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:clickClackDelay
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(runClickClackTimer)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];

    [avClick play];
    sleep(clickClackDelay);
    [avClack play];
    sleep(clickClackDelay);

    NSLog(@"Play sound every %.2f", clickClackDelay);

    clickClackDelay -= 0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly define `BOOL` instance in .h file:

```
 BOOL play;
```

Now in add this `timer` where to need to `play sound in delay`.

```
 NSTimer *clickClack = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:clickClackDelay
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(runClickClackTimer)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
```

Its method which will play delay according to clickClackDelay is:

```
-(void)runClickClackTimer
{
  if(play)
  {
    play = FALSE;
    [avClick play];
  }
  else
  {
    play = TRUE;
    [avClack play];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first sleep timer and the NSTimer will both delay for the same amount of time, 1 second, therefore calling

```
[avClack play];
```

in the first instance of runClickClackTimer at the same time as

```
[avClick play];
```

in the second instance of runClickClackTimer.

I would set up two separate NSTimers that call two separate functions, perhaps runClickTimer and runClackTimer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. What would be the best way to stagger the two methods?

Comment: I'd first try setting the two timers for different periods, and then bringing them closer to the same. Or perhaps putting a short sleep before the setting of the two timers. I'd have to play with it. As a side note, you could set the timer to Repeats:YES and then you don't need to keep starting the timer.

Comment: I did that intentionally. The timer is running at an increasing speed, so the reset is necessary.

Comment: I need the delay to be dynamic in that it adjusts according to the variable clickClackDelay. Not sure if the sleep would accomplish that.